# Touchpad not working in Ubuntu live session

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse

I just put ubuntu on my usb drive and chose "try ubuntu without installing".

But the touchpad doesnt work anymore in the desktop.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: the latest oneUbuntu 18.04.1 LTS